# Regex lookahead or lookbehind expressions

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have to check **in a single regex** if a string:

1. Contains substring-1
2. Does not contain substring-2

No matter the position of both substrings.

1. "**substring-2** bla bla bla **substring-1**": no match
2. "**substring-1** bla bla bla **substring-2**": no match
3. "**substring-2** bla bla bla **substring-1** bla bla **substring-2**": no match
4. "bla bla bla **substring-1** bla bla": MATCH

I have been trying using lookaorund expressions but cannot check if substring-2 is behind or before substring-1.

```
(?<!substring-2.*)(?!.*substring-2)substring-1
```

This expression would fit my case if substring-2 is not before and after substring-1. So if substring-2 appears both before and after the regex will work but if only appears after or before will not work.

**How can I translate this into an OR condition, so the lookaorund expressions are combined into an OR?**

NOTE: the input string will be multiline so it can contain newline characters.

NOTE: the regex must be .NET compatible

Comment: Do need to check if the whole string fits your requirements, or to actually retrieve the `substring-1`?

Comment: I need to get back substring-1

Comment: The input string will be multiline: do you need to check for `substring-2` on each line or on the whole string?

Comment: substring-2 should not be anywhere in the whole multiline string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform the check at the beginning of the string, then store `substring-1` in the first capturing group:

```
(?s)^(?!.*substring-2).*(substring-1)
```

`(?s)` is just the inline way of turning on the `dot matches all` (even newlines) flag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just **one** negative lookahead - [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pF2xZ5).

```
^(?!.*substring-2).*substring-1
```

Answer (score 1):

The general technique to achieve this is to concatenate the "rules" with lookaheads:

`^(?=.*substring-1)(?!.*substring-2)`

If you want `substring-3` to fail. Then add another lookahead:

`^(?=.*substring-1)(?!.*substring-2)(?!.*substring-3)`

Don't forget the `s` modifier to match newlines with the dot.